# Moving file directly into zip file

Tags: c#

I'm trying move `Source_File.mp4` into `Destination_Zip.zip` directly. I'm currently trying it by creating a new entry `Transfer.mp4` and copying the bytes over. The code runs to the end but the file is never added to the ZIP file. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if this isn't possible.

```
string sourceFile = basePath + "Source_File.mp4";
string destinationZip = basePath + "Desintation_Zip.zip";

using (var file = File.OpenRead(destinationZip))
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.SetLength(file.Length);
    file.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)file.Length);

    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("Transfer.mp4");
        using (var destinationStream = entry.Open())
        using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
        {
            sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason is as @kalexi points out. You are reading your archive as a `MemoryStream`, representing that stream as a `ZipArchive` and adding to the archive, but where are you actually saving that `MemoryStream` back over the file on disk? Relying on the native Zip API will handle reading & persisting changes.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that even though you've read the file and altered it, you didn't write anything back, i.e. changes persisted to `MemoryStream`, and didn't go anywhere after that.

You could try this (assumes you're using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`):

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(destinationZip, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var entry = zip.CreateEntry("Transfer.mp4");
    using (var destinationStream = entry.Open())
    using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
    {
        sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
    }
}
```

Or, if you're using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile`, do this:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destinationZip, FileMode.Open))
using (var zip = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var entry = zip.CreateEntry("Transfer.mp4");
    using (var destinationStream = entry.Open())
    using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
    {
        sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to import the library for `ZipFile`, it says there is no definition for `Open`

Comment: Are you using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`? If you're using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile`, that might be why. Give me a couple of sec, I should be able to update the answer for it real quick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why my initial code did not work, but I got it working by doing this instead:

```
string sourceFile = basePath + "Source_File.mp4";
string destinationZip = basePath + "Desintation_Zip.zip";

using (var destinationZipFileStream = new FileStream(destinationZip, FileMode.Open))
using (var destinationZipArchive = new ZipArchive(destinationZipFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry destinationWriter = destinationZipArchive.CreateEntry("Transfer.mp4");
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(destinationWriter.Open()))
    using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
    {
        sourceStream.CopyTo(writer.BaseStream);
    }
}
```

**Note**: you will need to double check to make sure the file doesn't exist already or else you'll make duplicate files this way.

Comment: Ah, OP-skeeted :)